# How are we to visualise the process of reciprocation? (Turning a number into its reciprocal)

Tags: functions

My question is about indicating the answer to the various questions written in the following paragraph. It’s mainly; exactly how does  reciprocation work? How is it’s mechanism? How are we to look at this function as a whole?

How do we visualise the idea, of something (say x) over one and one over it(x) becoming the reciprocal of itself(1/x); the idea of a variable raised to -1? How do we relate it with functions like squaring, cubing and raising to 0? How do we relate the input and output of this function?

Like we can visualise a function of multiplication by a constant (like f(x)=10x) as simply increasing the input by a constant factor, so the graph keeps increasing. And you can also see it like the value of Δf(x) increasing by a constant amount, giving a straight line graph. One simple idea in the case of reciprocation is that as ‘x’ increases the value of Δf(x) keeps decreasing but think how does it decrease, how is the rate working(the differentiation)?

Are there any other functions who work in a similar manner?

I know the question seems vague, but I am not an expert at Mathematics and I am simply trying to dive deep into the concept of slightly more  uncommon functions. A simple explanation of reciprocation will unlock many concepts of physics and mathematics for me.

Comment: Please don't assign tags if you don't know what they mean.  This has nothing to do with any of these thing, except function.

Comment: A geometric mechanism is [inversion about a circle](https://www.google.com/search?q=circle+inversion+geometry) when the circle's radius is $1.$

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for visual intuition. Here is one possibility. Imagine the number line where the numbers are spaced logarithmically (as in a logarithmic scale, if you are familiar). On this line, a positive number and its reciprocal will both lie the same distance from 1, but on opposite sides. So to carry every number to its reciprocal, you can flip the whole line over while fixing 1 in place.

Comment: A slide rule...